# CRM 2011 Solution (upgrade) fails to import, downloaded Logfile reveals nothing where to look next?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, importerror

I'm upgrading an existing Solution into CRM 2011 RU13 and as usual it is all misery.

```
The import of solution: Solution Name failed.
```

I download the log file which has a Solution worksheet with this in it.

```
The import failed. For more information, see the related error messages.
```

I open the Components worksheet is shows me that most of the items are processed except for these

- Client Extensions : sitemap
- 2 Security Roles
- Root components insertion
- Dependencies Calculation

There are no error messages or code in this log

I have checked Settings -> System Jobs and there are no entries at the Date & Time I attempted the import.

Where do I look next? 
What do I do?

Naturally the world is going to end if I can't come up with a solution soon.

EDIT: Turning on Trace helped...although the exceptions captured there were a complete mystery.

What was causing me grief is that our DBA had turned replication on the database on so we could query / report off a mirror. It seems SQL replication locks up a bunch of fields and makes it difficult to perform schema changes.

also if you're going to use replication you'll need to run these commands

```
sp_configure 'max text repl size', 2147483647
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Comment: Could you post the exceptions you found?

Comment: I'll look into getting access to the machine with the trace logs

Comment: sorry, the admin deleted to trace when he was experimenting after replication was removed from sql.

To recreate my situation apply sql replication to a crm database and then import a solution that make a schema change eg add a new field to and entity. you'll get plenty of trace to trawl through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Platform tracing is probably a good place to start.

[How to enable tracing in Microsoft Dynamics CRM](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907490)